# ckfinder - file permissions on Windows 2008R2 using php and FTP connectors

Tags: php, windows, ftp, file-permissions, ckfinder

Happy New Year!

My site is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2. Within ckfinder 3 I am using the php connector to upload files and I have always had trouble with file permissions. To use ckfinder, I've had to change the permissions to 'modify' for the users group for the folder ckfinder is pointing to. This works but I'm getting a bit sick of deleting all those files hackers keep putting in the image folders.

I see there are security setting available in CKfinder but I guess they are only useful on a Unix host.

Is there any way to implement a similar security mechanism in php on windows?

I am trying to set up ckfinder so it uses an FTP connector instead. I've almost got it working but I get a permissions error, again.

I have added error reporting to the ....CKFinder\Backend\Adapter\Ftp.php file, and now I then see "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'ftp_chdir(): End"

So now I'm thinking it's due to the FTP site being hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2 platform.

Am I on the right track - is there a setting in Ckfinder or FTP in IIS 7 that I can't find?

Thanks in eager anticipation,

Michael